# Removing rows in NumPy efficiently

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large numpy array with a lot of ID values (call it X):

```
X:
id   rating
1    88
2    99
3    77
4    66
...
```

etc.  I also have another numpy array of "bad IDs" -- which signify rows I'd like to remove from X.

```
B: [2, 3]
```

So when I'm done, I'd like:

```
X:
id   rating
1    88
4    66
```

What is the cleanest way to do this, without iterating?

Comment: Maybe relevant to your interests: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962980/selecting-rows-from-numpy-ndarray

Comment: Specifically the highest-voted solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the fastest way I could come up with:

```
import numpy

x = numpy.arange(1000000, dtype=numpy.int32).reshape((-1,2))
bad = numpy.arange(0, 1000000, 2000, dtype=numpy.int32)

print x.shape
print bad.shape

cleared = numpy.delete(x, numpy.where(numpy.in1d(x[:,0], bad)), 0)
print cleared.shape
```

This prints:

```
(500000, 2)
(500,)
(499500, 2)
```

and runs much faster than a ufunc. It will use some extra memory, but whether that's okay for you depends on how big your array is.

**Explanation:**

- The [numpy.in1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) returns an array the same size as `x`
  containing `True` if the element is in the `bad` array, and
  `False` otherwise.
- The [numpy.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) turns that `True`/`False` array into an array of integers containing the index values where the array was `True`.
- It then passes the index locations to [numpy.delete](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html), telling it to delete along the first axis (0)

Comment: +1, i suspect this is the best solution (avoids a ufunc and is very fast compared to mine).

Comment: thanks! This is much faster for me than the solution referenced in the other comments (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962980/selecting-rows-from-numpy-ndarray)

Answer (score 2):

reproduce the problem spec from OP:

```
X = NP.array('1 88 2 99 3 77 4 66'.split(), dtype=int).reshape(4, 2)
bad_ids = [3,2]
bad_ideas = set(bad_ideas)    # see jterrance comment below this Answer
```

*Vectorize* a bult-in from Python's membership tests--i.e., *X in Y* syntax

```
@NP.vectorize
def filter_bad_ids(id) :
    return id not in bad_ids


>>> X_clean = X[filter_bad_ids(X[:,0])]
>>> X_clean                                # result
   array([[ 1, 88],
          [ 4, 66]])
```

Comment: Doesn't ``in`` take O(N) time for a list? You should probably make ``bad_ids = set([3,2])``

Comment: @jterrance--*thanks* (edited my Answer in accord w/ your comment).

Comment: Appreciate the help, but the other solution performs significantly faster on my data set.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely delete the information for bad ID's, try this:

```
x = x[numpy.in1d(x[:,0], bad, invert=True)]
```

This solution uses fairly little memory and should be very fast.  (bad is converted to a numpy array, so should not be a set for this to work, see the note in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html)
If bad is very small, it might be a little faster to do instead:

```
from functools import reduce
x = x[~reduce(numpy.logical_or, (x[:,0] == b for b in bad))]
```

Note: The first line is required only in Python3.
This also uses little memory because of the use of a generator.